# Can this be done in a one-liner?

Tags: chmod, netcat

Is there a way to do these two lines of code in one line?

```
nc -l 17500 > listenToNetcat.txt
chmod 754 listenToNetcat.txt
```

Comment: Why don't you set your `umask` beforehand so the file will get the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob in this.
How would it look like if it would be done like you said?
I just started to learn these command lines and it is very difficult, I was glad I found the two lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nc -l 17500 >> listenToNetcat.txt |xargs chmod 754 listenToNetcat.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me so quick. I'm just a newbie and starting to learn how all of this works.
Many thanks.